# python .loc with some condition(string, regex etc)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, substring

I am willing to get subset of the dataframe. And the condition is that, the value of certain column starts with the string 'HOUS'. How should I do?.

```
df.loc[df.id.startswith('HOUS')]
```

Answer (score 1):

I should have searched more.

Here is the solution.

```
df[df.id.str.startswith('HOUS')]
```